# Accessing session variable in second php page

Tags: php

My first php file is basic.php

```
   <?php
       session_start();
   ?>

   <html>
       <body>
       <a href="basic2.php? name=qadeerhussain"> click on it</a>
           <?php 
               $_session['username']="qadeerhussain";
               print $_session['username'];
           ?>
       </body>
   </html>
```

Out put of  `basic.php` is: click on it `qadeerhussain` my second `basic2.php` page is

```
   <?php
       session_start();
   ?>
   <html>
       <body>   
           <?php 
               print $_SESSION['username'];
           ?>
       </body>
   </html>
```

but it give me the following exception:

```
Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\wamp\www\test\basic2.php on line 12
```

Comment: PHP variables are case-sensitive: `$_session` is not `$_SESSION`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP variables are case-sensitive.So replace **$_session** to **$_SESSION**

Comment: but now it give me the following exception:Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\wamp\www\test\basic2.php on line 10

Answer (score 1):

Cause is upper case SESSION.. Not lowercase

Comment: but now it give me the following exception:Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\wamp\www\test\basic2.php on line 10

Answer (score 1):

your session variable should be named `$_SESSION` not `$_session`

Comment: but now it give me the following exception:Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\wamp\www\test\basic2.php on line 10